# Is there a term describing countries taking foreign citizens as hostage?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

English is my second language, and I am wondering is there a term that describes when countries take foreign citizens or dual citizens as hostage or arrest them on conspiracy/espionage charges all to pressure their government?

The reason I am asking this is I feel like it is getting pretty common approach with dictatorship governments and I thought maybe there is a term for it.

Some of the examples include:

- [British citizen prisoned in Iran](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2020/nov/02/nazanin-zaghari-ratcliffe-avoids-being-returned-to-jail)
- [U.S. citizen prisoned in Turkey](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/12/world/europe/turkey-us-pastor-andrew-brunson.html)
- [Australian citizen detained in Iran](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/nov/26/kylie-moore-gilberts-release-shows-dangers-of-making-deals-with-iran)
- [French resident prisoned and executed in Iran](https://www.economist.com/middle-east-and-africa/2020/12/16/why-iran-abducted-and-hanged-ruhollah-zam)

Comment: Kidnapping? . . . .

Comment: Using such people as "bargaining chips"/"detained as bargaining chips" seems a fairly common phrase e.g. https://www.hrw.org/news/2018/09/26/iran-targeting-dual-citizens-foreigners https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4481826/North-Korea-detained-citizen.html but I'm unaware if there is anything more succinct and specific. You could try reading reports like these but I don't think you'll find anything. (A related thing is the use of "human shields" which refers to keeping foreign prisoners so you can't get bombed, as done by Saddam Hussein.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think found the word I was looking for. "Hostage Diplomacy"

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostage_diplomacy#:%7E:text=Hostage%20diplomacy%20is%20the%20taking,then%20held%20as%20bargaining%20chips.)